# Phonegap - Cordova 2.1 ios 4.3.5 ondeviceready not firing

Tags: iphone, xcode, cordova, ios4

I created a phonegap app for ios. After submitting it to Apple itunes they rejected the project because I was not supporting IOS 6.

So, I installed Xcode 4.5, 
I updated the project to cordova 2.1

And it runs perfectly on ios 6 simulator.!!!

The BAD news are that is not working in my ios 4.3.5 iphone device.
When I use the cordova 2.0, it works under ios 4.3.5, but ios 6 is not supported...

I found that cordova 2.1 and xcode 4.5 doesn't support lower than ios 4.3 , but this is 4.3.5.

Does it has to do with the iphone hardware?
It is a 3Gs.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had to update all the included plugins to 2.1 compatible ones.

(facebook).

So if anyone comes across it, this is the solution.

Thanx